# I have a problem playing a midi file with midi-js

Tags: javascript, file, midi

I have this code block for starting MIDI playback when clicking a button, but it's not working properly. When I press the button, nothing happens. Can anyone see what might be causing this issue?

```js
function startMidiPlayback() {
  console.log("pepe");
  MIDI.loadPlugin({
    soundfontUrl: "https://gleitz.github.io/midi-js-soundfonts/FluidR3_GM/",
    instrument: "piano",
    onsuccess: function() {
      MIDI.Player.loadFile({
        url: "testo.mid",
        soundfont: "soundfont.dls",
        onsuccess: function() {
          MIDI.Player.start();
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

// Wait for the DOM to be fully loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // Add an event listener to the button
  const playButton = document.getElementById("playButton");
  playButton.addEventListener("click", startMidiPlayback);
});
```

Note: This question is related to a previous question, but I am not repeating the context here.

Comment: What is `MIDI`? Where is that supposed to come from? I suspect you have some errors reported in your console

Comment: Nope, no errors, i added a library called midi-js

Comment: How have you included that library? Looking at [their examples](https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/#code-examples---from-the-repo), it seems you need quite a few specific `<script>` tags

Comment: yeah, i am using replit and it imported the package via a script tag whose src is a link to the library, it works, i console.logged the MIDI object and there are all its properties and methods

Comment: Got a reproduction link?

Comment: https://replit.com/@busyneuron/midis#script.js

Comment: I get two errors reported when running it... _"Silently denying site request for MIDI access because no devices were detected. You may need to restart your browser after connecting a new device."_ and _"Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: WebMIDI requires a site permission add-on to activate"_. Since your script does not request access, I don't see how it could possibly work

Comment: That's weird i am not getting any error in the console, how do i fix it?

Comment: Are you clicking on the play button?

Comment: i am. in the console only appears a "pepe" as it is supposed to, i added that as a debugging log to see if the button works

Comment: don't worry, i am trying a different approach, thanks for your time